# Splashscreen can not navigate to the redirected page after seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create login with session using sharedpreferences and combine it with splashscreen but not going well, please kindly help..

Here is my code,

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future cekSession() async {
      SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool session = (preferences.getBool("session") ?? false);
      if (session == true) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
      } else {
        preferences.setBool("session", true);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: new SplashScreen(
          seconds: 3,

          // I got error around here
          navigateAfterSeconds: cekSession(), 

          title: new Text('Welcome !'),
          image: new Image.asset("assets/image.png"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
          photoSize: 100.0,
          loaderColor: Colors.blue),
    );

  }
}
```

error in the terminal said,
[image: Terminal]

error in the device,

[image]

Comment: try, **new** keyword in front of **MaterialPageRoute**

Comment: @JayGadariya Not working dude, have something else in mind..?

Comment: is your screen showing asset image on your mobile screen?

Comment: Nope, It's error right after I restarted the device.. @JayGadariya

Comment: if your image is there in assets folder and if you have mention it in **pubspec.yaml**?

Comment: I think that's not the case, because I've tried to directly redirect to my login page without session checking and it's working, but when I used the session checking it's not..

Comment: Based on error given inside the terminal, `navigateAfterSeconds` parameter should pass either `String` or `Widget`, not a `Future` as you did above

Comment: You're putting a method that returns a future in a place where you're supposed to either put a string that points to a named page or a widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can check session in `main` 
`navigateAfterSeconds` need widget 
code snippet

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  bool session = (preferences.getBool("session") ?? false);
...
navigateAfterSeconds: initScreen == "Login" ? Login() : MainPage(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

String initScreen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  bool session = (preferences.getBool("session") ?? false);
  if (session == true) {
    initScreen = "MainPage";
  } else {
    preferences.setBool("session", true);
    initScreen = "Login";
  }
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SplashScreen(
          seconds: 3,
          navigateAfterSeconds: initScreen == "Login" ? Login() : MainPage(),
          title: Text(
            'Welcome In SplashScreen',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          image: Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/TyCSG9A.png'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          styleTextUnderTheLoader: TextStyle(),
          photoSize: 100.0,
          onClick: () => print("Flutter Egypt"),
          loaderColor: Colors.red),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Login");
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Main Page");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `navigateAfterSeconds` does not receive `Future`, try to pass a widget instead. Take a `StateFul Widget`. You need to declare a bool `isLoggiedIn` need to evaluate your checkSession result in `initState` before moving to another screen.

```
bool isLoggiedIn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkSession();
  }
void checkSession(){
setState{(
isLoggiedIn= your value from sharedpref
)}
}
```

then on behalf of `isLoggiedIn` value you need to pass widget like this,

```
if (session == true) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
      } else {
        preferences.setBool("session", true);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      }
```